# Jasmin spy listens on AJAX Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasmine

I am trying to check if data gets sent to the server by spying on jQuery’s ajax method. Everything works until I add a 'done' function to the ajax post.

The error I get from Jasmine is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Jasmin spec:

```
describe("Post New Project Definition", function () {
    it("should post to GeoServer", function () {

        var information = {"i am": Math.random()};

        spyOn($, "ajax");

        addProjectDefinition.send(information);

        expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            method: "POST",
            url: "../svir/add_project_definition",
            data: information
        });

    });
});
```

My Ajax call:

```
function addProjectDefinition() {}

    addProjectDefinition.send = function(information) {
        var foobar = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "../svir/add_project_definition",
            data: information
        });

        // NOT WORKING
        foobar.done(function(){
            console.log('Hi I'm done:');
        });

};
```

Comment: One thing I notice is that your `console.log` has an extra single quote that's ending the string  prematurely. Use double quotes on the outside. `console.log("Hi I'm done:');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace this line in your test:

```
spyOn($, "ajax");
```

With:

```
spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function() { return { done: function() {}}});
```